# DataGridView and System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies when load from entity

Tags: c#, datagridview, entity-framework-6, entity

I am looking for a solution from a few days. I have simple base:

[image]

and simple code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
public partial class Form_test
{
    private _dbContext Db = new _dbContex();
    private void Form_test()
    {
        Db.BooksAuthors.Load();
        DGVBookAuthors.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = Db.BooksAuthors.Local.ToBindingList };
    }
}
```

The effect is:

[image]

How to additionaly display columns with Books.title and Authors.name with leaved DataBinding?. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Entities reflect the data model. Views should have their own representation of a model based on what information you want to display.

For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class BookViewModel
{
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public int AuthorId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when loading your data source:

```
var books = DB.BookAuthors.Select(x => new BookViewModel
{
    BookId = x.Book.id,
    Author = x.Author.id,
    Title = x.Book.title,
    Author = x.Author.name
}).ToList();

DGVBookAuthors.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = books };
```

Entities reflect the data state. You can project entities into view models suited to the views you want to display. When your view calls back to the controller with IDs and data, you use those IDs to load entities once again, and update their state if applicable.

Passing entities to a view means sending a lot more data to the client than is needed, and is prone to problems like what you encountered, plus other serialization errors.

Regarding your initial schema: I would suspect that you wouldn't need a many-to-many relationship between books and authors. While 1 author may have many books, a book should really only have one author. This would simplify the schema so that there is no BookAuthor table, just an AuthorId (idAuthor) on the Book table. Then the query would be simplified to:

```
var books = DB.Books.Select(x => new BookViewModel
{
    BookId = x.id,
    Author = x.Author.id,
    Title = x.title,
    Author = x.Author.name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to have possibliy to edit DataGridView after show data. Simply I want to use Db.SaveChanges(); after edit DGV by user. I have many-to-many relationship between books and authors because in my scheme Books can have many authors from Authors.

Comment: You should still consider view models. Entities returned from a view are *not* associated to a DBContext, they are deserialized C# objects. Attaching them to the request DbContext allows stale data to overwrite your DB, and makes data vulnerable to tampering. Your data grid can edit view models to pass back. Tools like Automapper can easily copy across allowed values with one `Map(src, dest)` call after you validate the input.